# Set X Axis dynamically with Chart JS

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I want to make a line chart with new accounts made within a certain time range.

Is possible to give a `start` timestamp and a `stop` timestamp so X Axis to be set acordingly with your range? For example, if range is 30days, I'd like to have labels like 1 Oct, 9 Oct etc. But if the range is 5 years, I'd like to have labels like 2017, 2018, 2019...

```
var config = {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
        datasets: [{
            label: "New Users",
            backgroundColor: 'blue',
            borderColor: 'blue',
            data: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]                
        }]
    },
    options: {            
        scales: {
            xAxes: [{
                type: 'time',
                time: {                       
                    min: 1471174953000,
                    max: 1473853353000
                }
            }]
        }
    }
};

var ctx = document.getElementById("chart").getContext("2d");
var chart = new Chart(ctx, config);
```

Comment: Don't think so. How would it correlate your data points to a specific point in time?

Comment: @rory_za - So the solution is to remove labels from X Axis and to display the date on data point's tooltip with a callback?